# Why this png image appears twice?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a problem with this png image, I´m trying to put it in the middle of the screen an resize it, but it keeps appearing a fragment of the image net to it, I c (its my first web page, I accept any corrections)checked the code, I have only one image linked. Can you help me please?

it should look like this

[image: it should look like this]

But the png appears doubled

[image: But the png appears doubled]

html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ehands.css">


</head>


    <body>


        <div>
<h1>Ehandcipation</h1>
</div>
<div>
 <img src = "logoehands.png"
          />
 </div>
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video> 
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1000;
  overflow: hidden
}    

body{
    text-align: : center;

}


div{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);

    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 37%;
      margin-left: px; 
    margin-top: -25px; 

}

h1 { 
 color:#fff;
text-align:center;  
    position: abosulte;

}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('logoehands.png');


}
```

Comment: please provide the pic too to us.

Comment: background image is a css property to put an image at any element , but img is to show image, so you show image via img tag and add background img to the img tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove one of those choices :

- html : `src = "logoehands.png"`
- css : `background-image: url('logoehands.png');`

Answer (score 1):

What's up?

So, the image is appearing twice because you put the image src to be the logoehands.png and in the CSS you put background-image, just remove the background-image in the CSS